# Center div displayed over the top of page

Tags: css

I have a div displaying over the top of the page in a modal-ish way.  What I'm not sure of is how to center it from left to right.

Here is the CSS i have.  I know the that left 0; needs to be changed but not sure how.

```
.adminBack {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    z-index: 999;
    width: 1298px;
    margin-left: 649px;
    margin-top: 100px;
    padding: 5px 0px;   
}
```

Comment: Try to put it inside a div with `{width:100%}` and `adminBack{ margin: 0px auto;}`.i guess that should do the job.

Comment: left:25%;right:25%; ?

Comment: I think you should need help of javascript/JQuery ???

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Some new CSS to try:

```
.adminBack {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    z-index: 999;
    width: 1298px;
    height: 590px;
    margin-left: -649px; /*   Minus half of element width*    */
    margin-top: -300px;  /*   Minus half of element height*   */
    padding: 5px 0px;
}

/*
     *includes padding and borders.
*/
```

### [Demo](http://jsbin.com/oyawog/1/edit) | [Fullscreen](http://jsbin.com/oyawog/1/quiet)

Comment: how you maintain screen sizes with this fix pixels? Let me Know?

Comment: @Sarfaraz I updated my answer with a demo. I'm not sure what you mean in your comment. The modal will center in the middle of the page regardless of screen size.

Comment: yes i got it but i was thinking when it goes to dynamic i mean the main div has no fixed width? then what is the solution?

Comment: Instead of negative margin you can use: `transform: translate(-50%, -50%);`